# webkit-font-smoothing: suddenly different results in chrome and safari

Tags: css, fonts, rendering, font-face, webfonts

I used to have the same output in both webkit browsers (Chrome & Safari) but suddenly (and I don't know what I could have changed the rendering in Chrome looks crappy.

**this is my html**

```
<li class="cat-item term term-workshops"><a href="/workshops">Workshops</a></li>
```

**and this is my css**

```
.term a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
    font-smooth:always;
}

.term-workshops a {
    text-transform:lowercase;
    font-family:"Custom-Family", sans-serif;
    font-size:1.4em;
    margin-top:.1em;
}
```

---

*The output in Safari looks good (it used to look the same in Chrome)*

[image: SAFARI]

*The output in Chrome looks suddenly crappy*

[image: SAFARI]

Any idea of why that could make a difference in both webkit browsers?
I know it looks crappy in Firefox since there is no `font-smoothing` option, but it should look the same in Chrome and Safari if possible.

What could I have been able to change in my css that the output looks suddenly different? I know it looked the same in both browsers!

Comment: Chrome just had another update - 22.0.1229.79

Comment: Oh, wow, damnit! Can't sometimes thing just work like I want them to.

Answer (score 8):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/0vqp1bnkaoE

> -webkit-font-smoothing no longer works.
>   Google Chrome team intentionally changed this behavior. Seems
>   font-smoothing wasn't applied "properly" on OSX in previous versions.

Comment: It's just been confirmed that, the Chrome team will be reverting to the previous behaviour in an upcoming patch. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152304

Comment: Oh, i see... Unluckly, we can't know when!

Comment: Is there any other "trick" or way to make the font look/render better?

Comment: @matt have a look at this article: http://css-tricks.com/beefing-up-dull-text-in-webkit/ and this: http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2010/12/the-benefits-of-opentypecff-over-truetype.html