# how to access anti aliasing method of a font with CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, antialiasing

I've had this problem in a lot of different webs. You have a font which has different anti-aliasing options, the designer uses the same font with different anti-aliasing options on different parts of the text on the web. So there is a difference between some elements.

In this case I have sharp, crisp, strong and smooth. I've used a font generator to get the code to access it via @font-face. Even so, I also have the original .otf if important to know. Is there a method to access this?

I upload a picture of what I mean and my actual code:

[image]

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'light';
    src: url('../_fnt/light/gothamrnd-light.eot');
    src: url('../_fnt/light/gothamrnd-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../_fnt/light/gothamrnd-light.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../_fnt/light/gothamrnd-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../_fnt/light/gothamrnd-light.svg#../_fnt/light/gothamrnd-light') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to control the rendering of text in that way. Those are Photoshop specific settings as it has its own rendering engine, they aren't even available to other programs.

Actually, different browsers will render the text in different ways, and even the same browser on different computers will render it differently depending on the system settings.

If you make the page look exactly like the design in one browser, it will look rather different in another browser. You should normally test it in different browsers and try to make it look as close as possible to the design in most of them, and make sure that it's not too far from the design in any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Only WebKit browsers on Mac OS X have recognized a CSS property related to font smoothing, namely `-webkit-font-smoothing`. Even there, it’s unclear what’s happening, as they seem to be removing the `antialiazed` value, see [webkit-font-smoothing: suddenly different results in chrome and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646592/webkit-font-smoothing-suddenly-different-results-in-chrome-and-safari)

So for practical purposes, regard font smoothing as being out of your hands as an author, and test your fonts under different smoothing options to check that the results are at least tolerable.

Comment: Ok, its clear. My desires to have the design to 100% accuracy cannot be met. For now I used font-weight: lighter. It does make some effect, but its very subtil... thank you anyway for your help!